# MySQL Workbench crashing when trying to do a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to use a spring boot application with MySQL Workbench however when I try to make a SELECT query the app constantly crashed and it seems like it only happens when I do a SELECT because it works when I create a database and use an INSERT statement.

I'm on MacOS Ventura, has anyone ran into this issue as well? If so how was it fixed?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but the issue persists.

**Edit**

This is the error I see.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               MySQLWorkbench [4040]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.32.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-02-02 14:09:45.6928 -0400
OS Version:            macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        F7C82EFE-672B-7D8B-2236-0CE707EC500E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D960C8C9-39F1-456B-96B6-12CB04D76D93

Time Awake Since Boot: 21000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5002 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [4040]
```

There's much more though but it's too much text.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Workbench, you should file a bug report.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, is it possible to dualboot into a basic PC environment that only has Workbench installed and try to access the table from there?  Curious to see if you get the  same error, or if it ends up working.

Comment: @Enoobong Hey, unfortunately I did not :(

Comment: I just went down to  8.0.31.

Comment: @Enoobong I just did the same and it works now, thanks!

Comment: 8.0.31 works, thanks